# Exposing C++ interface in boost python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

Sample code to illustrate:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual int foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  virtual int foo()
  {
    return 42;
  }
};

Base* get_base()
{
  return new Derived;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libTestMod)
{
  py::class_<Base>("Base", py::no_init)
    .def("foo", py::pure_virtual(&Base::foo));

  py::def("get_base", get_base, py::return_internal_reference<>()); //ignore mem leak
}
```

- Base::foo will not be overridden in python
- Base:foo will be implemented in c++ but that should not be exposed to python

Tried the above code but fails to compile.

**update:**
Compilation Error:

```
/path/to/boostlib/boost/1.53.0-0/common/include/boost/python/object/value_holder.hpp:66:11: error: cannot declare field 'boost_1_53_0::python::objects::value_holder<Base>::m_held' to be of abstract type 'Base'
Main.C:59:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Base':
Main.C:61:15: note:         virtual int Base::foo()
```

Comment: Would you mind to show the compilation errors, or what's your question?

Comment: Included compilation errors.

Comment: Obviously `py::class_<Base>("Base", py::no_init)` wants to create an instance of `Base`, which isn't possible because `Base` is abstract. I'm not experienced with boost python though, can't tell what's wrong in detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Abstract C++ classes cannot be exposed in this manner to Boost.Python.  The Boost.Python [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.class_virtual_functions) gives examples as to how to expose pure virtual functions.  In short, when decorating methods with `boost::python::pure_virtual`, a wrapper type needs to be created to allow C++ to polymorphic resolve the virtual function, and the virtual function implementation will delegate resolving the function polymorphically in the Python object's hierarchy.

```cpp
struct BaseWrap : Base, boost::python::wrapper<Base>
{
  int foo()
  {
    return this->get_override("foo")();
  }
};

...

boost::python::class_<BaseWrap>("Base", ...)
  .def("foo", boost::python::pure_virtual(&Base::foo))
  ;
```

For details, when a type is exposed via `boost::python::class_`, `HeldType` defaults to the type being exposed, and the `HeldType` is constructed within a Python object.  The [`class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec) documentation states:

> Template Parameter:
>
> - `T`: The class being wrapped
> - `HeldType`: Specifies the type that is actually embedded in a Python object wrapping a `T` instance [...].  Defaults to `T`.

Hence, the `boost::python::class_<Base>` will fail, because `T = Base` and `HeldType = Base`, and Boost.Python will try to instantiate an object of `HeldType` into a Python object that represents an instance of `Base`.  This instantiation will fail as `Base` is an abstract class.

---

Here is a complete example showing the use of a `BaseWrap` class.

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct Base
{
  virtual int foo() = 0;
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  virtual int foo()
  {
    return 42;
  }
};

Base* get_base()
{
  return new Derived;
}

namespace python = boost::python;

/// @brief Wrapper that will provide a non-abstract type for Base.
struct BaseWrap : Base, python::wrapper<Base>
{
  BaseWrap() {}

  BaseWrap(const Base& rhs)
    : Base(rhs)
  {}

  int foo()
  {
    return this->get_override("foo")();
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  python::class_<BaseWrap>("Base")
    .def("foo", python::pure_virtual(&Base::foo));
    ;

  python::def("get_base", &get_base,
              python::return_value_policy<python::manage_new_object>());
}
```

and its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> class Spam(example.Base):
...     pass
... 
>>> Spam().foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Pure virtual function called
>>> class Egg(example.Base):
...     def foo(self):
...         return 100
... 
>>> e = Egg()
>>> e.foo()
100
>>> d = example.get_base()
>>> d.foo()
42
```

---

It is possible to expose an abstract class in Boost.Python by exposing it with no default initializer (`boost::python::no_init`) and non-copyable (`boost::noncopyable`).  The lack of an initializer prevents Python types from deriving from it effectively preventing overriding.  Additionally, the implementation detail that `Base::foo()` is implemented within C++ by `Derived` is inconsequential.  If Python should not know about a `foo()` method at all, then omit exposing it via `def()`.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

struct Base
{
  virtual int foo() = 0;
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived
  : public Base
{
  virtual int foo()
  {
    return 42;
  }
};

struct OtherDerived
  : public Base
{
  virtual int foo()
  {
    return 24;
  }
};

Base* get_base()
{
  return new Derived;
}

Base* get_other_base()
{
  return new OtherDerived;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<Base, boost::noncopyable>("Base", python::no_init)
    ;

  python::class_<Derived, python::bases<Base> >("Derived", python::no_init)
    .def("foo", &Base::foo)
    ;

  python::class_<OtherDerived, python::bases<Base> >(
      "OtherDerived", python::no_init)
    ;

  python::def("get_base", &get_base,
              python::return_value_policy<python::manage_new_object>());

  python::def("get_other_base", &get_other_base,
              python::return_value_policy<python::manage_new_object>());
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> b = example.get_base()
>>> b.foo()
42
>>> b = example.get_other_base()
>>> b.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'OtherDerived' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Comment: The above solution works only if all of `Base`'s pure virtual functions are exposed in python. Is there a way to expose only a subset of `Base`'s functions?

Comment: @balki: The type exposed above has no pure virtual functions, and exposing a type neither requires nor exposes members functions.  If `foo()` should not be exposed, then do not expose it via `def()` on the `class_`.  If the type returned from `get_base()` needs a narrower interface than the one provided by `BaseWrap`, then expose `Derived` as a type with only the desired methods, and the default `Bases` template parameter.

Comment: I see that we can avoid exposing in python by not specifying in `def`. However it requires `BaseWrap` to implement all the pure virtual functions. i.e rewrite `Base`'s interface with dummy impl. I guess there is no better way.

Answer (score 8):

Abstract classes actually **CAN** be exposed to Boost.Python without wrappers.
The trick is defining your class with *boost::noncopyable* and avoiding *pure_virtual* method wrappers.

Here is the corrected code (tested with Boost.Python 1.47.0 and Python 2.7.6):

```
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>

struct Base
{
  virtual int foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  virtual int foo()
  {
    return 42;
  }
};

Base* get_base()
{
  return new Derived;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libTestMod)
{
    namespace py = boost::python;

    py::class_<Base, boost::noncopyable>("Base", py::no_init)
        .def("foo", &Base::foo);

    py::def("get_base", get_base,
        py::return_value_policy<py::reference_existing_object>()); //ignore mem leak
}
```

Testing:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 31 2014, 16:04:58) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import libTestMod
>>> base = libTestMod.get_base()
>>> print base.foo()
42
```

Comment: How to I also export the derived class? If I do it with:
`py::class_<Derived, boost::noncopyable>("Derived", py::init<>()).def("foo", &Derived::foo);`
I get
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 3, in <module>
    print base.foo()
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Derived.foo(Derived)
did not match C++ signature:
    foo(Derived {lvalue})`

Comment: Export derived classes as: `py::class_<Derived, py::bases<Base> >("Derived");`
The foo() method will be inherited automatically.