# Boost Python - Abstract base class not building

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a base class (StandardObserver) with a pure virtual so I am wrapping it so that I can create instances in Python and be called back on them but it doesn't build.  I need to expose the base class as I need to pass the dervied class polymorphically but I also need to wrap the class as OnMessage is a pure virtual callback.

```
class Subscription::StandardObserver : public Subscription::Observer::Impl
{
public:
    typedef implementation::ObjectReference<StandardObserver> Ptr;
    class Context : public Observer::Context
    {
    public:
        Context(const Subscription& subscription, const Message& message, const Criteria& criteria) : Observer::Context(subscription, message, criteria) {}
    };

    virtual void OnMessage(const Context& context) = 0;
};

struct PyStandardObserver : public Subscription::StandardObserver, public wrapper<Subscription::StandardObserver>
{
     void OnMessage(const Subscription::StandardObserver::Context& context)
     {
          if (override f = this->get_override("OnMessage"))
                f(context);
     }
};
```

The boost::python

```
class_<Subscription::StandardObserver, boost::noncopyable >("SO", boost::python::no_init);

class_<Subscription::StandardObserver::Context>("Context", no_init);

class_<PyStandardObserver, bases<Subscription::StandardObserver>>("StandardObserver")
    .def("OnMessage", &PyStandardObserver::OnMessage);
```

The error:

```
 Error  4   error C2259: 'eapi::Subscription::StandardObserver' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054822/exposing-c-interface-in-boost-python